# Wildcard bash not working

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to make a case statement and i am using the following wildcards to make the diff between the arguments:

This is for a single IP:

```
case $1 in
//the argument is a single IP    
*.*.*.0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30|31`|32|33|34|35|36|37|38|39|40|41|42|43|44|45|46|47|48|49|50|51|52|53|54|55|56|57|58|59|60|61|62|63|64|65|66|67|68|69|70|71|72|73|74|75|76|77|78|79|80|81|82|83|84|85|86|87|88|89|90|91|92|93|94|95|96|97|98|99|100|101|102|103|104|105|106|107|108|109|110|111|112|113|114|115|116|117|118|119|120|121|122|123|124|125|126|127|128|129|130|131|132|133|134|135|136|137|138|139|140|141|142|143|144|145|146|147|148|149|150|151|152|153|154|155|156|157|158|159|160|161|162|163|164|165|166|167|168|169|170|171|172|173|174|175|176|177|178|179|180|181|182|183|184|185|186|187|188|189|190|191|192|193|194|195|196|197|198|199|200|201|202|203|204|205|206|207|208|209|210|211|212|213|214|215|216|217|218|219|220|221|222|223|224|225|226|227|228|229|230|231|232|233|234|235|236|237|238|239|240|241|242|243|244|245|246|247|248|249|250|251|252|253|254|255 )

        ....`
//the argument is a IP range

    `*.*.*.*-*.*.*.* )

    ....`
```

Even so, it seems that its not working, what am I doing wrong?

thanks,

Comment: It should make the difference between 127.0.0.1 and 127.0.0.1-127.0.0.5. for a single IP it should do a specific set of commands and for a IP range other commands.

Comment: Instead of such a huge switch, why not simple `if`?

Comment: and in if i will not have to use this wildcards ?

Comment: Bash is not JavaScript. Fix your syntax.

Comment: This seems like a problem that is solvable in bash, but the solution will not be very elegant. Have you considered using a different language for whatever problem it is that you are trying to solve?

Comment: Look my *bash only* function `checkIsIp` ... and ip calculation, there! http://serverfault.com/questions/461760/linux-create-shortcut-command/461831#461831

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the single IP, you have defined these alternatives

- `*.*.*.0`
- `1`
- `2`
- ...

and *not*

- `*.*.*.0`
- `*.*.*.1`
- `*.*.*.2`
- ...

The pattern type used here is called [`glob`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29).

If you really want to spell it out, you have to say

```
*.*.*.0|*.*.*.1|*.*.*.2|...)
```

When you want to have at most three characters, you can specify this as well

```
*.*.*.?|*.*.*.??|*.*.*.???)
```

or with at most three digits

```
*.*.*.[0-9]|*.*.*.[0-9][0-9]|*.*.*.[0-9][0-9][0-9])
```

but this allows e.g. `127.1.3.843` as well.

If you have

```
case "$arg" in
single-IP) ... ;;
IP-range) ... ;;
esac
```

it will first test single-IP, which always matches. To match ranges as well, you must list the pattern for the IP range first

```
case "$arg" in
IP-range) ... ;;
single-IP) ... ;;
esac
```

then it tests the IP range case first, and only if it doesn't match tests for the single IP pattern.

For a simplified test, see

```
case "$1" in
*.*.*.*-*.*.*.*) echo range ;;
*.*.*.*) echo single ;;
*) echo else ;;
esac
```

this gives

```
$ sh /tmp/a.sh 1.2.3.4
single
$ sh /tmp/a.sh 1.2.3.4-5.6.7.8
range
$ sh /tmp/a.sh 1.2.3
else
```

Comment: Is there a wildcard that can specify that there are only a maximum of 3 characters after the . ?

Comment: I have used the last one and for single IP and i am using *.*.*.[0-9]|*.*.*.[0-9][0-9]|*.*.*.[0-9][0-9][0-9]-*.*.*.[0-9]|*.*.*.[0-9][0-9]|*.*.*.[0-9][0-9][0-9]) for IP range. But it seems its not recognizing this case. It always goes to single IP

Comment: nicee, I have changed it, but now it only goes on the range, even if the argument its a single ip

Comment: @AlexisCimpu It works for me, please see small test example in the updated answer.

Comment: @AlexisCimpu If this doesn't work for some reason, show your current code in your question.

Comment: Bear in mind that this solution allows things that are no IPs at all!

Comment: I agree with @gniourf_gniourf! This is not robust! As SO's question title stand for *bash wildcards* only, this could be correct, but at all this is not *well*! Take time to test and look gniourf_gniourf's answer!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this little loop can help you:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob

is_a_byte() {
    local i
    for i do
       [[ "$i" = +([[:digit:]]) ]] && ((10#$i<=255)) || return 1 
    done
}

is_ip() {
    local ipn
    read -a ipn <<< "${1//./ }"
    if [[ "${#ipn[@]}" = 4 ]] && is_a_byte "${ipn[@]}"; then
       [[ "$2" ]] && printf -v "$2" "%s" $(( ((((((10#${ipn[0]}<<8)|10#${ipn[1]})<<8)|10#${ipn[2]})<<8)|10#${ipn[3]}) ))
       return 0
    else
       return 1
    fi
}

while IFS=- read -e -r -p "Enter an IP or an IP range: " -a ip; do
   if [[ -z ${ip[1]} ]]; then
      if is_ip "${ip[0]}" N; then
         echo "Valid IP ---> $N"
      else
         echo "${ip[0]} is not a valid IP"
      fi
   else
      if is_ip "${ip[0]}" N[0] && is_ip "${ip[1]}" N[1]; then
         ((N[0]>N[1])) && N=( "${N[1]}" "${N[0]}" )
         echo "Valid IP range ---> ${N[0]}-${N[1]}"
      else
         echo "${ip[0]}-${ip[1]} is not a valid IP range"
      fi
   fi
done
```

No grep, no subshell, only pure bash, and it is much more robust than a clumsy glob/regex, and I would say it's rather elegant `;-)`.

Comment: Hi! I find your `is_ip` near my `check_is_ip`: http://serverfault.com/questions/461760/linux-create-shortcut-command/461831#461831 ;-) Happy New Year!

Comment: @F.Hauri Very close, yes! The one I gave here is more "bashistic" though `;-)`. Happy New Year too!

Comment: Nice concept, I don't ever used `printf -v`. But for *test only*, U could add `[ "$2" ]`  before `printf`!

Comment: U could use `[ "$i" == $((i&255)) ]` for test *Is a byte*

Comment: And `read -a ipn <<< "${1//./ }"` will parse `$1` whithout the need of manipulating `IFS`.

Comment: @F.Hauri Followed some of your suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Nice work, thanks' +1, as I've learned something today! (I've surprised when reading `for i do`...)

Comment: @F.Hauri `for i do` is funny (some pretend it's more portable, but I don't care about that, we're talking about bash), and it's less keystrokes.

Comment: While bash if written in C, it's portable. I find many bashism funny, but I've already reached some case where old bash script won't work because of new features or worst: because of syntax changing between generation.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21986/discussion-between-f-hauri-and-gniourf-gniourf)